# finding rank from given order sequence

Tags: python, pandas, key

I have a 3 paths say (0,1,2) and want to check which is the fastest. I send 1 order on each path (triplet=>path0,1,2) and check for its sequence at the destination. This is done many times as a test and logged at source and destination like below

```
#Source log file
OrderID,PathCode
1000,0
2000,1
3000,2
4000,1
5000,2
6000,0
7000,2
8000,1
9000,0
#Dest log file doesnt contain the path it came from, it only knows the sequence as below
OrderID
3000
1000
2000
5000
4000
6000
9000
8000
7000
```

I need to find how many times pathCode0 is fastest,how many time pathCode1 is fastest,how many time pathCode1 is fastest out of total tests.

How to do it in pandas or python. I somehow need to manage a key of orderID which tells me the PathCode. grep each orderID from destination file to find pathCode is not a good way. Once we get pathCode in the sequence (destination log) we need to check order for each triplet and rank paths.
(Can change the question title if required)

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Absolutely no, just that I am unable to understand how to approach this problem. This is just a part of a bigger problem and I'm currently stuck at finding the ranks