# map according to key column in different file using python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a log file like below

Source log file

```
OrderID,PathCode
1000,0
2000,1
3000,2
4000,1
5000,2
6000,0
7000,2
8000,1
9000,0
```

But Destination log file doesnt contain the PathCode it came from, it only knows the sequence as below.

```
OrderID
3000
9999 #Ignore this since not in source OrderID
1000
2000
5000
9991 #Ignore this since not in source OrderID
4000
6000
9000
8000
7000
9998 #Ignore this since not in source OrderID
```

How to add PathCode to the dest file. OrderID is always unique

Expected Output

```
OrderID,PathCode
3000,2
1000,0
2000,1
5000,2
4000,1
6000,0
9000,0
8000,1
7000,2
```

Basically I have to sort source file according to sequence given in destination file

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Could you add your code?

Comment: @pvg added details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map

```
dest['pathcode'] = dest['OrderID'].map(source.set_index('OrderID')['PathCode'])
```

You get

```
    OrderID pathcode
0   3000    2
1   1000    0
2   2000    1
3   5000    2
4   4000    1
5   6000    0
6   9000    0
7   8000    1
8   7000    2
```

To get the group of 3 rows and find the first pathcode try,

```
dest.iloc[0::3, 1].value_counts() #df.iloc[0::3] returns row no 0,3,6,9 etc

2    2
0    1
```

so pathcode 2 came first 2 times and 0, 1 time.

EDIT:
I tried the code with your test case dest file. The map works as expected and you need to dropna but you also need to reindex for the slice to work.

```
dest.dropna(inplace=True)
dest.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
dest.iloc[0::3, 1].value_counts()
```

You get

```
2    2
0    1
```

Comment: Thats what i required, this result is in triplet form(every 3 row form a triplet). Is there a way to find how many times pathCode=2 came 1st (in a group of 3 rows) and so on.  Refer for detail what I am trying to say http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703257/finding-rank-from-given-order-sequence and thanks a lot

Comment: @pythonRcpp, if the solution works for you, you can accept the answer

Comment: I added a fail case (when orderID is in dest but not in source. We should ignore those cases, can this be included as a check. Many thanks

Comment: I used `dest.dropna()` I hope it does not affect the sequence order or any other thing.

Comment: What is the importance of `dest.reset_index`, why is it required? I could not understand "slice to work"

Comment: You will understand if you see your dataframe before and after reset_index. Dropna causes some missing indices which need to be reset